# Raid 0 to Raid 6

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I currently have 4x 4TB NVME drives in an enclosure. I originally started with 2, and consolidated my full photo library onto this. I currently have a duplicate of the first data set on the newer set of 2x nvme drives, so I at least had some safety. Two pairs of drives in Raid 0, So it shows as 2x 8TB drives separately.

Sadly 8TB is no longer enough, and I still need some redundancy. I need to do this merge without losing data, because these are now essentially my ONLY copies of all my photos.

I believe I want to migrate to a Raid 6 setup. If I read it correctly, I would have 12TB storage, with at least 1 drive failure safety.

HOW do I perform this migration?

Comment: You essentially cannot given the hardware restraints you describe. I hope you know RAID 0, allows for zero drive faults, if a single disk fails in your current RAID your data is gone. If my math is write a 4x4TB RAID 6 would only be 8TB not 12TB since you would end up with 2 disks for stripe and 2 disk parity

Comment: [Yeah 4x4TB RAID 6 is 8TB](https://www.seagate.com/products/nas-drives/raid-calculator/), only when you end up with 5+x4TB do you end up with more than 8TB

Comment: There’s certainly room for improvement with your current setup, but do you need _availability_? If not, the backup you _must create anyway_ is enough redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't address what the better/best RAID setup is, but the HOW.

The HOW for any change to RAID or any other storage changes is pretty much the same:

1. Backup the data carefully and verify that the backup is successful and correct.
2. Make the changes to the storage setup.
3. Restore the backup to the new storage system.

I don't know of any system that would promise you can arrange/rearrange storage drives and retain the data safely, but even if they did promise such as thing I would not trust that. Backing up the data, making the changes, and restoring the data (if necessary) is the only correct and safe way to make any changes to storage systems.

Whether you go with RAID6 or something else based on your needs, follow these steps to safely complete these changes.

Comment: Thank you. I started down this path, but my "spiny" drive wasn't big enough with the other things already backed-up there. Thankfully I am a hoarder, and grabbed a couple other old drives that I could safely wipe, and am in the process of splitting the "other" backup on to these, and then copying over the 7.6TB from NVME's. It is just REALLY REALLY REALLY slow. 

Will leave this open just a bit longer to see if someone does have another option. As I imagine it'll take at least 10+ hrs to do this migration... and well, #murphysLaw :(

Comment: Yea, backups are transfers, and transfers are slow. There are some protocols and methods that are faster, depending on the types of files and storage devices at either end of the transfer, but there's only so much you can do about transferring huuuuuge volumes of data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're a photographer and you're using the DAS / encloser to edit files. Having a RAID 0 with NVME drives must be really fast.

1st I recommend you purchase 1 or 2 external hard drives to back up you're existing data. Get one that uses a USB-c cable for faster data transfers.

Then I would think about getting anther DAS (direct attached storage) or a NAS (network attached storage). This is why, your current setup has a focus on speed. You just don't need speed if you're not working on the files or need to display the photo's all the time. I would use this 2nd device to hold the stuff you're not currently working on. Your current setup can be setup to automatically move or copy the closed files to the 2nd device, thus creating a backup of all your files. After this is setup the external hard drives, I recommended your purchase above, can then be used to backup the 2nd device (DAS / NAS). In the long run having a 2nd device will be cheaper than having a large NVME RAID. You will be able to have much larger RAID if you use larger capacity spinning drives. Not to mention there cheaper too. You can also use SSDs if you prefer.

RAID - you mentioned needing 12TB for a 6TB RAID. That would be correct for RAID 10, which is RAID 1 and 0 combined. I would stick with RAID 0 if you do regular backups. If you don't see yourself doing backups then do RAID 5.

Sorry if this went a little long.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, a faster spinny drive would be great, and on my list, but after dropping so much cash on the NVME's I was hoping to update without having to drop more. I am moving from a spinny drive NAS to this DAS, because it was just too painfully slow (1st-world-problems I admit). Because I'm a nomad, having an extra, bulky, HDD is effectively a deal breaker. I'm trying to get my DAS to be complete, and then do delta uploads to cloud service moving forward as my backup.

Comment: @mondo The main point I was trying to make is, it is cheaper to go SSD or HDD because both options are cheaper and you can get higher capacity. Just use the NVME's for what your currently working on and offload the stuff your not working on to slower media. Anyway good luck.